# Vim color schemes and SAS programs

Tags: vim, gvim, sas

I have a problem that when I open SAS programs (.sas files) in Vim, the colors look very ugly (a mix of white and black background, etc.).

Example here: This is how vim looks when I open a SAS file (`setf=sas`)

[image: This is how vim looks when I open a SAS file (setf=sas)]

My colorscheme is koehler.

I have tried changing colorscheme, but then this happens:

[image: When I run :colo delek, vim looks like this. Syntax highlighting seems to have disappeared.]

So I run `:setf sas`, and syntax highlighting appears again with correct colors.

[image: So I run :setf sas, and syntax highlighting appears again with correct colors.]

I am not sure what the underlying problem is here: It could be a problem in the colorscheme 'koehler', however, since syntax highlighting just disappears when I change colorscheme, it might rather be a problem in filytype detection.

How do I fix this?

Can I somehow configure vim to use a different colorscheme for a specific filetype? (e.g. use delek for .sas files?)

*Update 2015-05-15*:
Appearently, the problem only occurs in gvim and not Vim run in a terminal.
I have a screenshot here of how it looks when I open a .sas file in Vim from a terminal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AALq4.jpg

*Update 2016-01-15*:

Problem was fixed by editing sas.vim and changing all the constant color definitions to HiLinks:

```
HiLink sComment Comment
HiLink sCard    String
HiLink sDate_Time   Special
HiLink sKeyword Structure
HiLink sFmtInfmt    Special
HiLink sString  String
HiLink sText    String
HiLink sNumber  Number
HiLink sProc    Structure
HiLink sSection Structure
HiLink mDefine  Define
HiLink mKeyword Structure
HiLink mReference   Structure
HiLink mSection Structure
HiLink mText    String
```

Comment: Does `:redraw` also fix the issue?!

Comment: :redraw does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Too bad. I would have guessed terminal issues (wrong `$TERM` value), but at least one of your screenshots shows GVIM is affected, too. Strange.

Comment: All screenshots are from gvim. I have not tried in the console, but I will and update with results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explaining this behaviour

Syntax highlighting is meant to modify a colour scheme. The default SAS syntax highlighting is meant to modify a normal colour scheme, like I use, and then it is suitable to show `data` as blue on white. On a reverse video scheme, like `koehler`, it is not.

When you change your colour scheme to a normal one, vim throws away your syntax highlighting, because it might well be incompatible with the newly selected colour scheme.

### You can solve this

by creating a custom syntax highlighting for SAS in reverse video.
To do this, edit your `sas.vim` file *(on my windows system in `C:\Program Files (x84)\vim74\syntax`)*, setting all `guibg` to `Black`, replacint `guifg=Blue` `guifg=LightBlue` and applying similar changes till it looks alright

Comment: This solved my problem. I will make an update the actual changes to sas.vim that fixed this.